# Windows Defender в обычном приложении

Tags: c#

Windows Defender ругается на мое приложение, это обычный игровой лаунчер, который проверяет наличие файлов с помощью этой либы: https://github.com/Facepunch/Facepunch.Steamworks

Скачивая всё напрямую с Workshop, даже не с моих серверов. А после запускает игру

```cs
Process process1 = new Process()
{
    StartInfo = {
        FileName = Settings.SkipBattlEye ? "DayZ_x64.exe" : "DayZ_BE.exe",
        Arguments = string.Join(" ", executeArgs),
        WorkingDirectory = Settings.GamePath,
        Verb = Settings.RunAsAdmin ? "runas" : ""
    }
};
try
{
    process1.Start();
}
finally
{
    UpdateProgressLabel("Приятной игры!");
    //Application.Exit();
}
```

Вопрос заключается в следующем, как сделать так, чтобы Defender не ругался на твое приложение? Есть какие-то рекомендации? Ибо там код максимально простой и небольшой.

Comment: Подписать код своим личным сертификатом безопасности. И я не понял что значит "ругается".

Comment: Есть гайд? Чтобы подпись себе сделать.

Comment: Его не делают, а покупают. Code Sign certificate.